# getting array of arrays from List using lambda?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, lambda

I am trying to query data from List with Lambda expression. Below is my Users class

**Users**

```
 Id,Name,Password, EmailAddress
```

Required data would be an array of arrays using two columns from list **Name** and **password** .Select(c =>  c.LastUpdatedDate + "," + c.LastUpdatedDate  ).ToArray();. Result wold be something like belwo:

```
[["Name1","***"],["Name2","+++"],["Name3","///"]]
```

Can you please guide and help me selecting this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by creating a new array inside a Linq `Select` (I assume you want an object array since you have an int and string in there):

```
object[][] result = users.Select(user => new object[] { user.Id, user.Name }).ToArray();
```

If both columns are string, then the syntax is almost identical -- just replace both `object[]` with `string[]`:

```
string[][] result = users.Select(user => new string[] { user.Id, user.Name }).ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks, it really helped me. Just a small edit please, what if both columns are string.

Comment: +1. Depending on types of fields instead of `user => new object[]...` you can use `user => new string[]...` or just `user => new[]...`

Comment: @Toubi it's almost the same, see my edit, and also Alexei's note (implicitly-typed arrays)